# onClick in RecyclerView from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a RecyclerView list in which I display all the documents (each document has its own collection with data) from Firestore, and the question is how to display its corresponding data from Firestore in a new fragment when clicking on a list item

My Firestore collection
[image]
In the Recycler View, I display only the name and image for each item, but after clicking on the item, I want to open a new fragment where all the fields from the collection will be

ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val documentsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Card>>()

    fun getDocuments() {
        if (auth.currentUser != null){
            db.collection("cards")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    val cardList = mutableListOf<Card>()
                    for (document in documents) {
                        val card = document.toObject(Card::class.java)
                        cardList.add(card)
                    }
                    documentsLiveData.value = cardList
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.e("Document error", exception.message.toString())
                }
        }
        else{
            Log.e("Document error", "Toast error")
        }

    }

    fun getDocumentsLiveData(): LiveData<List<Card>> {
        return documentsLiveData
    }
    

}
```

Adapter

```
class CardAdapter(private val context: Context,
                  private val list: List<Card>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = list[position]
        holder.itemView.card_name.text = item.name
        holder.itemView.card_description.text = item.description
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(item.img)
            .into(holder.itemView.card_img)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size

    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    }
}
```

MainFragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

        viewModel.getDocumentsLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { cardList ->
            binding.progBar.visibility = View.GONE
            val adapter = CardAdapter(requireContext(), cardList)
            binding.mainRecycler.adapter = adapter
        }
        viewModel.getDocuments()
    }
```

I tried to do a search by element id, but it didn't work out for me

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have no errors in the code, I just showed it

Comment: Please also explain, what you mean by "each document has its own collection with data"? And does `Log.e("Document error", exception.message.toString())` print something?

Comment: @AlexMamo I display all the documents from Firestore in Recyclerview, for each item in RecyclerView I display the name and img fields, but when I click on the item I want to open a new fragment and display all the fields name, description, img, phone, address

Comment: Please also add the content of your `MyViewHolder` class, as it's empty in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To display the corresponding data from Firestore in a new fragment when clicking on a list item, you can follow these steps:

In your CardAdapter, add a click listener to the item view in the onBindViewHolder method:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = list[position]
    holder.itemView.card_name.text = item.name
    holder.itemView.card_description.text = item.description
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(item.img)
        .into(holder.itemView.card_img)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailFragment(item.id)
        it.findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
}
```

In your MainFragment, create a new NavDirections object that includes the document ID as an argument:

```
val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailFragment(item.id)
```

Create a new DetailFragment that will display the corresponding data from Firestore. In the onCreateView method of the DetailFragment, retrieve the document ID from the arguments and use it to query Firestore for the corresponding document:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val args = DetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val docRef = db.collection("cards").document(args.documentId)

    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            val card = document.toObject(Card::class.java)
            // Display the data in the UI
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false)
}
```

In the DetailFragment, display the corresponding data from Firestore in the UI. You can use the card object that you retrieved from Firestore in step 3 to populate the UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Best way:
firstly show collections list
secondly show files/collections list of select collection.